# is $(document).on(event, '#id .class') faster than $(document).on(event, '.class')

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

So I know that if you **query an element** by ID, it's way faster than by only class.
Is this true in the case binding events to dynamically created elements. 
Example:

`$(document).on('click', '#id .class', someFunction);`

vs

`$(document).on('click', '.class', someFunction);`

Assume  I have **really a lot of** elements on my page.
When I **click** on the element binded by the function above, will the 1st method call `someFunction` faster than the 2nd method?

Comment: The difference is almost certainly inconsequential.  But in case it isn't, just spend 5 minutes and run some tests to find out.

Comment: I think jquery uses `document.querySelectorAll()` with newer browsers anyway. which is built into the browser.

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/

Comment: this just reeks of premature optimization

Comment: I think every situation is different.  In general, using selectors that are easy to maintain is far more important than selectors that are fast (which usually means class selectors, in my opinion).  If you run into a situation where the javascript is taking too long, try out different things and find out which is fastest in your situation.

Comment: why is my question downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you understand how delegated event handling works in jQuery, then your first version with `'#id .class'` is just making more work for the event handling system.   As others have said, you would have to run some tests to see if the difference is even measurable, much less consequential.

To help you understand, here's how the delegated event handling for this works:

```
 $(document).on('click', '#id .class', someFunction);
```

An event handler for the `click` event is registered on the `document` object.   Then, anytime a click event bubbles up to the `document` object, the jQuery system is called and it has to check to see if the event target matches the `'#id .class'` selector.  This is a bit of work.  First it has to see if the object itself (or a parent) matches `.class`, then it has to search up the parent chain from where it finds a match to see if it finds `#id`.

Your second version doesn't have to search up the parent chain for the `#id`.  So, if that isn't required for accurately targeting only the items you want, then you should just go with your second option:

```
$(document).on('click', '.class', someFunction);
```

simply because it makes less work for the code to do.

Comment: I'm pretty sure jQuery has to check if the element clicked has this element as its parent too, i.e. you click `span` inside of a `button`, but the `button` is the selector used in `$.fn.on()`.

Comment: @alex - yes, if the clicked element doesn't match `.class`, then it will also check parents to see if that class is inherited.  But either way, the `#id` adds more work if it isn't needed for accurate targeting.